# Converting bash to zsh: declare function and if statement

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have copied this code from somewhere and am trying to modify it for my needs. It was designed for `bash` but I am running it under `zsh`.

I always have trouble running bash scripts under zsh, as there seems to be quite a few differences between the two languages(?). Is anyone able to tell me what I need to modify here so that it works with `zsh`?

```
declare -a files=(
  "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/exports" # Exports
  "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/aliases" # Aliases
  "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/functions" # Functions
  "$HOME/.z.sh" # z binary from https://github.com/rupa/z
  "$NVM_HOME/nvm.sh" # NVM
  "$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh"
)

# If these files are readable, source them
for index in ${!files[*]}
do
  if [ -r ${files[$index]} ]; then
    source ${files[$index]}
  fi
done

unset files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://dev.0x50.de/projects/ftzsh/repository/revisions/master/entry/zshrc.d/zshrc.real) a `~/.zshrc` that sources a bunch of other files:

```
# Load the zsh files. 
# This is taken from Frank Terbeck's ZSH setup.
for rc in ~/.zshrc.d/???-*.z; do
    if [[ -r ${rc} ]] ; then
        zprintf 1 "zshrc: loading %s\n" "$rc"
        source "$rc"
    else    
        zprintf 0 "zshrc: could not load %s\n" "$rc"
    fi      
done    
unset rc
```

This'll `source` files in `~/.zshrc.d/` which have a filename beginning with a 3-digit number (for example, `421-Name.zsh`).

The advantage of this method is that it allows you to have a single directory (`~/.zshrc.d/`) containing all your startup-scripts. You can then add to / remove from that directory without having to touch multiple files (you don't have to edit `~/.zshrc` every time you add a script).

To change the filenames, edit this line:

```
for rc in ~/.zshrc.d/???-*.z; do
```

The directory it's searching is `~/.zshrd.d/`. If you don't want a 3-digit prefix, remove the `???-`. The extension (`.z`) can also be changed here.

Note: the `?` doesn't actually match a `digit`, my mistake. From `man zshexpn`:

```
?      Matches any character.
```

Comment: This looks good! What if I didn't want to have the requirement of a 3-digit prefix?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Added a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with bash than zsh, but this should work in either:

```
# zsh's declare (/typeset) command doesn't allow arrays to be assigned as
# they're declared. Actually, arrays don't really have to be declared, you can
# just create them by assigning an array value; but for completeness...
declare -a files
# Comments aren't recognized inside an array declaration, so leave them out
files=(
    "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/exports"
    "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/aliases"
    "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/functions"
    "$HOME/.z.sh"
    "$NVM_HOME/nvm.sh"
    "$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh"
)

# If these files are readable, source them
# Note: rather than iterating over a list of array indexes and using them to
# pull out the array elements, I've switched this to iterating over the array
# elements directly. It's simpler, and works the same in both bash and zsh.
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    if [ -r "$file" ]; then
        # Note that if any of the files have bashisms, they may break in zsh
        source "$file"
    fi
done

unset files
```